# My first Python GUI program generating error

Tags: python, pyqt4

I tried following link to write my first Python GUI app:

[Setting up IDE and creating a cross platform Qt Python GUI application](http://popdevelop.com/2010/04/setting-up-ide-and-creating-a-cross-platform-qt-python-gui-application/)

I configured the settings exactly as shown in the screenshots, and just pasted that example given over there, but it is giving error. It is not able to find QtGui in PyQt4 folder. The only difference is that I am using Aptana Studio 3 Beta with PyDev plugin instead of Eclipse.

The screenshot of my development environment is here:
[image]

Comment: Do you have pyqt installed? Is it in your pythonpath?

Comment: @Falmarri: Yes it is. I also noticed that PyQt4 brings SIP think with it, whereas I installed another version of SIP as shown in that link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I installed PyQt4 with the latest windows installer it missed adding the path to the dll files, too.
Instead of adding another item to my already bloated path line I copied the contents of the C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\bin folder up to the main PyQt folder (C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4) and that stopped the 'dll not found' errors that python was throwing.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. However, I still see few red-underlines as warnings.

Comment: what might those warnings be?